# Unsubscribing from RxJava2/RxAndroid PublishSubject

Tags: rx-java2, publish-subscribe, rx-android, event-bus

I'm trying to replace EventBus with RxAndroid.

I want pageable fragments to subscribe/unsubscribe to an event source, these fragments get created and discarded relatively quickly, depending on how fast the user slides to a new page.

In EventBus I was able to add an decorated callback method (ie `@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)`) and register/unregister in the onStart/onStop methods of the fragment.

With RxJava2 I now create a `PublishSubject` object in a class

```
public static PublishSubject<List<Long>> m_psUpdatedDays = PublishSubject.create();
public static void publishUpdatedDays(List<Long> lDay) {
    m_psUpdatedDays.onNext(lDay);
}
```

and subscribe to this publisher in another class by calling the following in the Fragment's `onStart` method:

```
m_psUpdatedDays.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<List<Long>>() {
    @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}
    @Override public void onNext(List<Long> longs) {
      ...
      Update Fragment UI here
      ...
    }
    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {}
    @Override public void onComplete() {}
});
```

My question is how can I unsubscribe this new Observer when the Fragment's `onStop` method is called by the system?

Do I need to store the `Disposable` object which I get in the `onSubscribe` and then call `.dispose()` on it in the `onStop` method?

Comment: This issue is now solved for me. In addition to Sarath Kn's answer, this might be a helpful video https://caster.io/lessons/rxjava-2-compositedisposable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of a `CompositeDisposable` object, which can keep a list of disposables and all of them can be disposed together.

Create a `CompositeDisposable` instance in the base fragment level, keep on adding your disposables into it.

```
    public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
        protected CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mCompositeDisposable.clear();
            //clear will clear all, but can accept new disposable.
            // You can call it on `onPause` or `orDestroyView` events.
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mCompositeDisposable.dispose();
            //dispose will clear all and set isDisposed = true, so it will not accept any new disposable
        }
    }
```

In your fragments, subscribe to the Observable using the `subscribeWith` method, which gives you a `disposable` instantly and this disposable you can dispose later in the `onPause` or `onDestroy` events (wherever you want)

```
     public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {


            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                Disposable disposable = m_psUpdatedDays.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Long>>() { // Use `subscribeWith` instead of `subscribe`, which will give you back the disposable , which can be disposed later
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(List<Long> longs) {
                                // Update Fragment UI here
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                            }
                        });
                mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable); // add the disposable to the disposable list
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain the difference between using such a `CompositeDisposable` with `subscribeWith` and storing a reference to the `Disposable` passed in `onSubscribe`? I've implemented the latter and it seems to work like it should. Is there a benefit to using `CompositeDisposable` vs a `List<Disposable>`?

Comment: I've read on GitHub a comment stating "_dispose() means that you will no longer be able to add disposables to that composite disposable, clear() means you can - it just clears the disposables that are currently held within the instance._". Should I then use `.clear()` instead of `.dispose()` in the `onStop` method, since `onStart` will add a new `Disposable` to the already used `CompositeDisposable` when it is called again (ie App going into the background and later getting resumed)?

Comment: using a CompositeDisposable with `subscribeWith` and your implemetation are effectively the same. But `CompositeDisposable` becomes handy when you have more than one subscription.
 `CompositeDisposable` can hold all your disposables and unsubscribe from all in one step. Also `subscribeWith` reduces one method in your observer callback `void onSubscribe(Disposable d)` so that your observer becomes short

Comment: **Should I then use .clear() instead of .dispose() in the onStop method, since onStart will add a new Disposable to the already used CompositeDisposable** - Yes. Also you can call `dispose()` during `onDestroy` as I have shown in the code, since you can't have any new disposables afterwards